# Я пытаюсь скачать базу данных с фтп, но она скачивается поврежденной. Файлы с другими расширениями скачиваются нормально

Tags: java, ftp

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Ftp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        String server = "exampleip";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "examplename";
        String pass = "example";
        String remoteFilePath = "/example/example/example.db";
        String localFilePath = "C:/example/example/example/example.db";
        try {
            client.connect(server, port);
            client.login(user, pass);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(remoteFilePath);
            if (files.length > 0) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath);
                client.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, fos);
                fos.close();
            }
            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

С Ftp все нормально, проверял мой друг. Также он скачивал этот файл, и он был не повреждён.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, следует указать клиенту, что вы собираетесь скачивать *двоичный* файл, а не текстовый:

```java
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```